# Icons missing in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using [Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) and [Widgets](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets) from jQuery, but the icons does not appear. for eg the `Cross (X)` and `Plus-Minus (+-)` Icons.

When I load the page I et these errors.

```
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"
ui-bg_...100.png

"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png"
ui-ico...240.png

"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png"
ui-bg_...100.png
```

So, I downloaded the images, put it into the path specified, but then the `+- icons` appear twice at the extreme right and moreover only the column1 widgets are minimized. The `Close X` icon still not appears. Where I'm going wrong?

I would also like to know how to add remove widgets functionality?

Comment: i just checked the example that jui is providing and downloaded all images and place in the images folder... i am getting the 'X' icon.. just make sure u include the image with name 'ui-icons_888888_256x240.png'

Comment: widgets functionality - it sounds to me like you have a problem with your mark-up. view the source file on your page and run it through the validator and see what you get I'm going to guess that your page has incorrect mark-up which is causing the problem - [w3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: @BharathRallapalli-  Where should I keep this png file? I downloaded it and put it under the `/static/css/images`. But Cross icon still does not appears.

Comment: for the images to appear correctly, you also need the css, not just the image. in your css file, do you have a class like `.ui-icon`

Comment: Yes. With Content  `.ui-icon {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -99999px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: in that css files you will have the icon postions...check it once.., for confirmation pls take a raw html and try it , for sure you will get the icons if they have had kept in the images folder.

Comment: Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @user1162512 if you are still having trouble with this, can you add a link to a testing site so that I could take a look at your page?

Answer (score 46):

Just download it and save in your network location.

You can get it form the below.

https://code.google.com/p/vallalarblogs/downloads/detail?name=ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png&can=2&q=

reference: [www.thedeveloperblog.com](http://www.thedeveloperblog.com)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 36):

I have put the images in a convenient zip file:
http://zlab.co.za/lib_help/jquery-ui.css.images.zip

As the readme.txt file in the zip file reads:
Place the "images" folder in the same folder where your "jquery-ui.css" file is located.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: the link is now broken.

Comment: Link is really broken. If someone could fix this.

Comment: empty zip folder it is.

Comment: The zip file has nothing in it.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated

Comment: Thanks man... My issue resolved. and Link's working fine for me

Comment: Just download the images from the jQuery UI website. It's part of the package you download.  https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Key for me was moving the `jquery-ui.min.css` file into the `vendor/assets/images` directory and in that file updating the paths to the images: `url(images/file_name)` to not have 'images' because the files are in the same folder now

Comment: link not working

Answer (score 14):

Yeah I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy because I couldn't find the image.

This may help you out...

1. Look for a CSS file in your directories called jquery-ui.css
2. Open it up and search for ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png.

You will then see something like this...

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
}
```

And comment out the background and save the CSS document.  Or you can set an absolute path to that background property and see if that works for you. (i.e. background: #ffffff url(`http://.../image.png`);

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

I also got missing error image in JQUERY-UI. You can download images from https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/tree/grappelli_2_4/grappelli/static/grappelli/jquery/ui/css/custom-theme/images

Answer (score 2):

They arent missing, the path is wrong. Its looking in non-existent dir '**img**' for a file that is in dir '**images**'.

To fix either edit the file that declares the wrong path or as I did just make a softlink like

```
ln -s images img
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the right CSS and JS libraries helps, this solved it for me

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have workaround by setting background color instead of this missing icon. Here are the steps to follow:

- open relevant 'jquery-ui-x.-.x.css' file
- search for the missing file name in css file(eg: ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")
- Remove/comment the line that calls this background image
- instead add the following line to replace the background color 'background-color: #ffffff'

That will probably work

Answer (score 0):

I found icons were not displaying due to a difference in the casing (ie upper case vs lower case). The CSS file was using "FFFFFF" while the actual file was using "ffffff". Icons displayed for me once I changed the case to match.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in console that whenever I open my datepicker that I get 404 Not found error for this image file `ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png`

I downloaded the [image from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julienw/jquery-trap-input/master/lib/jquery/themes/base/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) and put it in my local under `jquery-ui` folder. Now the problem is solved.

Other image files found here:

https://github.com/julienw/jquery-trap-input/tree/master/lib/jquery/themes/base/images

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar error after adding jQuery-ui-tooltip component using bower. It downloads js + css files only, so I had to manually add images.

A good source to find all the images (for all standard themes) is this [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui).

Answer (score 0):

You need downbload the jQueryUI, this contains de images that you need

[enter link description here](https://jqueryui.com/)