# Jquery unknown image request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, range

I am using jquery 1.11.0.min.js. It is the pure jquery without any editing. Recently added jquery UI in my project. I am using jquery UI range slider(`range:false`). From there I am getting an error in my console. I am running a live server(localhost:8080).[image: Here is the image.]

I know, I didn't make this request.
It,s hard to explain the problem!


Is it my mistake?

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: jQuery UI looks for a theme (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icons missing in jQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515943/icons-missing-in-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably downloaded the UI Lightness theme.  When you download that build your zip file also contains a folder with images that the CSS file uses.  Copy that image folder to css a folder in your localhost.  `/css/images/`

[Folder Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYNkl.png)

Comment: Thanks [Edward Bernal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5924462/edward-bernal) for help!